# Anyone know why my logo is showing twice?

Tags: html, css

Anyone know why my logo is showing twice in ?

html:

```
<div id="logo"><a href="/Presidente Prude/oferta_do_dia" class="link">
        <font color="#264D73"><img src="/static/css/i/logo.png" alt="Cidade Louca" /></font></a></div>
```

css:

```
#logo {
width: 400px;
height: 125px;
margin: 3px 0 0 0;
position: absolute;
background: url(i/logo.png) no-repeat;
}
```

thank you ...

Comment: Can you please write your question so that it will be useful to people in the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you're setting it twice - once as the div's background and again as an img tag. Remove one of them, it should be fine.

```
<div id="logo">
    <a class="link" href="/Presidente Prude/oferta_do_dia">
        <font color="#264D73"><img alt="Cidade Louca" src="/static/css/i/logo.png"></font>  
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have the logo set as the background for the `#logo div` and you also have it as an image within that `div`.

Comment: On a side note, why do you have a `font` tag in there? Not only is it deprecated but it's unnecessary in the context you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

It's in your HTML, as an `<img>` inside the `#logo` div...

```
<div id="logo"><a href="/Presidente Prude/oferta_do_dia" class="link">
        <font color="#264D73"><img src="/static/css/i/logo.png" alt="Cidade Louca" /></font></a></div>
```

And it's also in your stylesheet, but this time as a background image of the `#logo` div...

```
#logo{width:400px;height:125px;margin:3px 0 0 0;position:absolute;background:url(i/logo.png) no-repeat}
```

---

Simply remove one or the other as per the following....

If you want the logo to have a hyperlink, leave the HTML alone (*except **remove** the unneeded `font` tags*) and modify your CSS to this...

```
#logo{width:400px;height:125px;margin:3px 0 0 0;position:absolute;}
```

If you do not care about attaching a hyperlink to the logo, leave the CSS alone and modify your HTML to this...

```
<div id="logo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have both a `<div id="logo">` with a `background-image` set, and a `<img>` tag inside that div with the `src` set to the same image.

Either remove the `background-image` attribute from the div, or remove the image.

Answer (score 0):

you have added the logo on your css:

```
 #logo {
 width: 400px;
 height: 125px;
 margin: 3px 0 0 0;
 position: absolute;
 background: url(i/logo.png) no-repeat;
 }
```

and in your html:

```
 <img src="/static/css/i/logo.png" alt="Cidade Louca">
```

you should delete one.